# How to replace tag element in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I am working in Vuejs.
How to replace `div` tag  to `button` tag ?

In DOM,

```
<div class="prev">prev</div>
<div class="next">next</div>
```

I want to make like this

```
<button class="prev">prev</button >
<button class="next">next</button >
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic component `component` ([doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components))

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tagName: 'div'
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(tagName) {
      this.tagName = tagName
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component :is="tagName" class="prev">Prev</component>
  <br/>
  <component :is="tagName" class="next">Next</component>
  <br/>
  <button @click="toggle('div')">Change To Div</button>
  <button @click="toggle('button')">Change To Button</button>
</div>
```